# Elegantly Insert Spaces During Loop Between Values Without Trailing Space

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Is there a way to elegantly insert whitespace (or any character or string, I suppose) between values during a loop?  For example, I want to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

to output the following:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

but this code actually leaves a whitespace trailing after the 5.  I could add a trim after the loop that snips off any whitespace, or do the first element before the loop, index i=2, and use print(" " + i) instead, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant and clean way to insert a value specifically *between* elements in a loop.

EDIT: as Arvind pointed out, it would be 0 1 2 3 4 5, not 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: What is ""*unclean*" about using `trim()`?

Comment: You have to check "do I have any items after this one", essentially, which means you're messing with the index _somewhere_.  Unless you use a library or built-in function, like [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Comment: Can you provide a practical example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: By the way, your code will print `0,1,2,3,4,5` and not `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: oops - yes, you're right, there will be a 0 at the start.

And there's nothing specifically "unclean" about using trim, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid an unnecessary action (i.e. adding a whitespace then immediately removing it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three alternative options:

[`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    sj.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

[`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--):

```
String joined = IntStream.range(0, 6)
                  .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

[`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
String[] strings = new String[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    strings[i] = i + "";
}
String joined = String.join(" ", strings);
```

Comment: yes, thank you! This is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  if (i < 5)
    System.out.print(i + " ");
  else System.out.println("" + i);
}  

.. or ..

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  System.out.print(i + " ");
}
System.out.println("" + i);

.. or ..

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  sb.append(i + " ");
}
String s = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s.trim());
```

All compatible with Java 1.0 or higher ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the methods mentioned by ernest_k are the most elegant ones.

You can also do it using a condition. I have printed `,` instead of space in the following example:

```
public class Mathrandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (i == 5) {
                System.out.print(i);
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + ",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
```